# Django oracle db settings

Tags: django, oracle, django-models, oracle11g, django-oracle

I just want to connect my local oracle db with my django project but my database credential is not working. Actually, I'm able to connect my oracle database via sql developer with that credential:
[image]

I just used that credential in django settings_py like that

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'INTERNAL',
        'USER': 'system',
        'PASSWORD': 'oracle',        
        'HOST':'localhost/xe',
        'PORT':'1521'
    }
}
```

and error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
web_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
web_1  |     utility.execute()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
web_1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
web_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
web_1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
web_1  |     loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in check_consistent_history
web_1  |     applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
web_1  |     self.ensure_schema()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
web_1  |     if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
web_1  |     return self._cursor()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
web_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
web_1  |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
web_1  |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 212, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     return Database.connect(self._connect_string(), **conn_params)
web_1  | django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

here its my listener status

```
 Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
    STATUS of the LISTENER
    ------------------------
    Alias                     LISTENER
    Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
    Start Date                28-DEC-2017 15:51:21
    Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 8 min. 36 sec
    Trace Level               off
    Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
    SNMP                      OFF
    Default Service           XE
    Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
    Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/e48c7c272f44/listener/alert/log.xml
    Listening Endpoints Summary...
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=e48c7c272f44)(PORT=1521)))
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=e48c7c272f44)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
    Services Summary...
    Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
     here its my listener status
```

Comment: I notice that the port in your Django configurations does not match the port in your SQL Developer Connection Dialogue (1521 vs 8080).  Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: i just tried many combinations im sorry i edited my question

Comment: actually how can i give my sid to settings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change `HOST` to `localhost' or '127.0.0.1` and SID is `NAME`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'xe',
        'USER': 'system',
        'PASSWORD': 'oracle',        
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'1521'
    }
}
```

For future references, if Oracle is configured with Service name instead of SID, then the configuration would be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': '127.0.0.1:1521/service.name',
        'USER': 'system',
        'PASSWORD': 'oracle',        
    }
}
```

Another thing to consider when working with Oracle in Django is that when you connect to Other Users (schema) database, you have to set `db_table` [Meta option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/) in Django models:

```
class OracleTable(models.Model):
    ... fields ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = '\"OTHERUSER\".\"ORACLETABLE\"'
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but now error turns 'django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener'

Comment: also we didn't give the databasename

Comment: Ok, did you install [cx_oracle](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and [Oracle Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html)? This error says it cannot find the database at 127.0.0.1:1521.

Comment: i added my listener status to question

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with Oracle running on Linux. Listener is running, but looks like Django/server cannot access it.

Comment: Also, try changing host to e48c7c272f44.

Comment: e48c7c272f44 it just docker container id it means localhost. But i'm able to connect and import data to my oracle which is in server. I dont understand why its not working on local :)

Answer (score 0):

NAME must be the `dsn` in `cx_Oracle.connect`, internally 'django.db.backends.oracle' try to connect with:

```py
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.connect(user=DATABASES['default']['USER'], password=DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'], dsn=DATABASES['default']['NAME'])
```